# Adjust UIImageView width according to height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, ios7, uiimage

I have hundreds of images in pdf format to use in my app. I am using an UIImage-PDF(https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF) category to show pdfs as images in my app. I am using this code

```
imageView = [[ UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100)];
```

to create an imageView and then adding image like that

```
[imageView setImage:[ UIImage imageWithPDFNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",imageName] atSize:CGSizeMake( 100, 100) ]];
```

Its working fine for square images, the problem is when width is greater than height. Images are shrunk.
What I want is, it should adjust image's width according to height. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `contentMode` of your Imageview to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` :

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Or

```
imageView.contentMode = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
UIImage *image =[ UIImage imageWithPDFNamed:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",imageName]];
[imageView setImage:image atSize:CGSizeMake( img.size.width, img.size.height) ]];
```

Comment: It won't help. It will give the 100px width if imageView. Actually i don't know the width of images, I want to fix the height and width should be set according to it.